# How to start another rails project along with the current project on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multiple-projects, diaspora

I was trying to run another **Rails project** along with **Diaspora**. 
I used the commands `rails server -p 3001` and `rails server -p 3002` in the same directory with `cd Diaspora`.
I visited **http 127.0.0.1:3001** and in project two **http 127.0.0.1:3002.** 
But I could open **diaspora server** only on both the ports.
I also tried to create a new project folder (Projects) in the directory **Diaspora**.

```
cd Diaspora
cd Projects
rails new project2
```

I got this output:

```
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
Type 'rails' for help.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to create a rails application in side another rails application ?

Comment: @BachanSmruty No,seperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you started Diaspora two times.

First make sure to you have Diaspora and your other projects alongside each other, not nested.

```
~/Diaspora
~/Projects
```

Then change into your projects folder, get the latest version of Rails and create a new project:

```
cd ~/Projects
gem install rails
rails new project2
cd project2
bundle install
```

There start your other project first:

```
cd ~/Projects/project2
bundle exec rails server -p 3002
```

Now in a *second* shell start Diaspora:

```
cd ~/Diaspora
bundle exec rails server -p 3001
```

Make sure to use `bundle exec` to avoid any version conflicts between the gems Diaspora uses and the gems your new application uses.

Comment: I can approve your answer without even checking it. Thank you:)